# Assigning Integer value in DataFrame but shows NaN in the specific position

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with 3 columns. I am applying one condition then received some indexes which satisfied my condition. Now I want to assign a new column and want to put one integer value but it shows NaN in every row in this column.

Here is my code:

```
 indexes =df1[(df1["A"] == 0) & (df1["B"] == 0)]
 
 df1.loc["indexes","score"]= 5
```

getting a result like that: I know without indexes will be NaN. But in the indexes position will be 5

```
A                                        0
B                                        0
score                                  NaN
```

but score should be score = 5.Please suggest to me what is my mistake

Comment: Did you mean `indexes` instead of `"indexes"`?

Comment: Yes..I am geting indexes where satisfy the condition

Comment: I think you added extra quotations.

Comment: Actually, I am new to python. I don't get what you mean. My question is I am assigning an integer value but getting NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `indexes` should probably be a *boolean mask/indexes* that you can code it as follows:

```
indexes = (df1["A"] == 0) & (df1["B"] == 0)
 
df1.loc[indexes,"score"]= 5
```

Note that there are 2 points you need to amend your code to make it work:

1. Use `indexes` as a variable name instead of the string `"indexes"` in the second line of code
2. In the first line of code, you don't need `df1[...]` to enclose the boolean mask/index.  Just the `&` of the 2 checking of equality with 0 will already form the boolean mask/index.

Comment: Thanks @SeaBean..You are right and solved it

Comment: @ShahedulIslam  Pleased to help!  Please also accept the solution if you can.